# Is there any multiparametric ROC-analysis

Tags: roc, validation, bivariate

I have a group of variables which are assumed to correlate with binary income(firm's default) in negative way(the bigger variable the less favourable firm's default to ocure). My task is to find a pairs of variables which descriminate income in the best way and somehow asses this ability. In case of looking for a good one variable I can apply ROC-analysis to investigatied discriminating ability of this variable. But what can I do in case of investigated pair of variables? Is there any biparametric generalisation of ROC-analysis? Or any bivariate one-tailed statistical test for my case?

Comment: Why don't you do a linear or logistic regression?

Comment: I need to substaniate selecting variables for building regression model.

Comment: A regression model will help you a lot with variable selection...

Answer (score 0):

Making a decision about a binary outcome using two variables requires making an assumption. This assumption should clarify how this pair of variables (or markers) will influence the outcome. A common approach is to create a dependent variable using logistic regression to combine these markers linearly. Then, this dependent variable is used in ROC analysis.

Let's consider an example. Suppose we have variables a, b, and c. We can perform a logistic regression model by combining all possible pairs of a, b, and c and calculate predicted probabilities for each observation (p1,p2 and p3) This would look like:

$$\log(p1/(1-p1) = \beta0 + \beta1*a + \beta2*b$$
$$\log(p2/(1-p2) = \beta0 + \beta1*b + \beta2*c$$
$$\log(p3/(1-p3) = \beta0 + \beta1*a + \beta2*c$$

Afterward, we can use ROC analysis on p1, p2, and p3, and determine the AUC values for each. These values can be presented as the AUC performance of the pairwise combinations of these markers. You can also use log odds (log(p1/(1-p1)) in the ROC analysis. It doesn't matter, since ROC analysis based on the ranking of values.

It's important to note that by conducting a model and defining beta coefficients based on the data, there is a risk of overfitting. This risk was not present when you make a ROC analysis for one variable. Therefore, it's recommended to divide the data into a training and test set. It's also best to report the AUC values of the analysis conducted on the test set.